# Is it possible to resize Canvas?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I would like to create `Canvas` with width along `x` is doubled the value along `y`. In `Plot`we can control the image size with `ImageSize -> Automatic -> {Y, X}`, I want to do the same thing but with `Canvas`. So, with `Plot` I do it like this

`Plot[x, {x, -10, 10}, ImageSize -> Automatic -> {400, 200}`]

[image]

but with `Canvas` the size is always fixed.

```
Canvas[]
```

[image]

Comment: try `Canvas[ImageSize->{400,200}]`?

Comment: similarly for other options in the list `Options[Canvas]` .

Comment: Well, I was doing a pity mistake because I tried that and did not work. Now It is working fine, Thanks @kglr